# Is a Gathered Swarm considered to be worn or carried by a Swarmkeeper Ranger?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, ranger, invisibility, swarm

According to the description of a Ranger's 3rd-level Swarmkeeper feature *Gathered Swarm*, it indicates:

> **Until you die, the swarm remains in your space**, crawling on you or
> flying and skittering around you within your space. **You determine its**
> **appearance, or you generate its appearance** rolling on the Swarm
> Appearance table. ([TCoE pg 60](https://marketplace.roll20.net/browse/bundle/8331/tashas-cauldron-of-everything))

According to the 10th-level ranger featue *Nature's Veil*, it indicates:

> As a bonus action, you can magically become invisible, **along with any
> equipment you are wearing or carrying**, until the start of your next
> turn. ([TCoE pg 57](https://marketplace.roll20.net/browse/bundle/8331/tashas-cauldron-of-everything))

---

Assuming the ranger has not chosen the appearance of the swarm to be invisible (can *invisible* even be considered an *appearance*?), **is the swarm considered to be worn or carried, or would the location of the ranger continue to be marked by the swarm?**

Comment: Why are you hinging your question on the issue of "worn or carried" xor not, instead of the issue of "equipment" xor not?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

#### Just let the swarm turn invisible when the ranger is invisible.

We’re probably getting too rules-focused if we try to answer this based on the swarm being worn or carried. Let’s just make a ruling that doesn’t nerf the ranger’s 10th level feature, that is, just let the swarm turn invisible when the ranger is invisible.

This is supported by the [Gathered Swarm](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#Swarmkeeper) feature description:

> Also, remember that the swarm’s appearance is yours to customize, and don’t feel confined to a single appearance. Perhaps the spirits’ look changes with the ranger’s mood or with the seasons. You decide!

Ergo,

> Dear diary, mood: invisible.

It’s up to the ranger what their swarm looks like anyway. “You can never truly be invisible even though your class features say they do that” is code for “don’t play this subclass”. Just let invisibility work. Pick whatever narrative reason you want. They’re “intangible spirits”, after all.

> I got a pocket, got a pocket full o’ <s>sunshine</s> butterflies